# Printing the output in Excel

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I am new to Python. I want to retrieve a tag value from multiple xml files and print it in an excel sheet. I tried and got the script working fine other than the excel printing part.

Here is my script

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
import xlwt
import os
def sh(dir):
for r,d,f in os.walk(dir):
    n=0
    for files in f:
        if files.endswith(".xml"):
            print files
            dom=parse(os.path.join(r, files))
            name = dom.getElementsByTagName('rev')
            title = dom.getElementsByTagName('title')
            a=xlwt.Workbook()
            sheet=a.add_sheet('sheet1')
            sheet.write(n, 0, files)
            sheet.write(n, 1, title[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
            sheet.write(n, 2, name[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
            n=n+1
            a.save('sha.xls')
            print title[0].firstChild.nodeValue
            print name[0].firstChild.nodeValue

sh("path")
```

The problem i stuck up with is, the output is printed in only in these columns (0, 0), (0, 1), (0,2).

e.g. if i want

```
A            B           C
D            E           F
G            H           I
```

my output

```
G            H           I
```

in (0,0), (0,1), (0,2).
So i understood that every new output is overridden on the existing one and only the final output is displayed. How can i avoid this and get what i wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your workbook and sheet outside the loop:

```
def sh(dir):   
    a = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = a.add_sheet('sheet1')
    n = 0
    for r,d,f in os.walk(dir):
        for files in f:
            if files.endswith(".xml"):
                print files
                dom=parse(os.path.join(r, files))
                name = dom.getElementsByTagName('rev')
                title = dom.getElementsByTagName('title')
                sheet.write(n, 0, files)
                sheet.write(n, 1, title[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
                sheet.write(n, 2, name[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
                n += 1
                print title[0].firstChild.nodeValue
                print name[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    a.save('sha.xls')
```

Also, if you don't need to search for xml files inside subdirectories, consider switching to [glob.glob()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) instead of using `os.walk()`:

```
def sh(dir):   
    a = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = a.add_sheet('sheet1')
    n = 0
    for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, '*.xml')):
        dom = parse(os.path.join(dir, f))
        name = dom.getElementsByTagName('rev')
        title = dom.getElementsByTagName('title')
        sheet.write(n, 0, f)
        sheet.write(n, 1, title[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
        sheet.write(n, 2, name[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
        n += 1
    a.save('sha.xls')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It did work fine. I didnt know the glob.glob() format, will try to use this. Thanks once again..:)